# XCData and White Spaces

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am currently writing a C# script to create an XML file based on a sample I have been given and typically I add an element like so:

```
node.Add(new XElement("NodeName", new XCData("Value")));
```

However on the XML sample it uses the following before the CDATA to create a space in the finished document (as transformed in html later):

```
&#160; // The XML is like:
<NodeName>&#160;&#160;<!CDATA[Value]]></NodeName>
```

I have tried to add spaces before the value in the XCData declaration but it always ignores them, is there some way I can either add the same as the XML, preserve any spaces I put in or perhaps tab before the value?

Comment: What char is &#160; anyway? It's not the normal space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a few spaces:

```
 node.Add(new XElement("NodeName", "  ", new XCData("Value")));
```

Comment: Didn't work I'm afraid, possibly as the white space is being ignored, can I somehow enforce it?

Comment: Yes sorry about my vagueness there. The white space is added to the xml document ok it seems.  The end document compiles with an xsl stylesheet and eventually saved as a html file.  On the html the whitespace is ignored as I would expect but I then changed the above empty spaces to &nbsp; but these just displayed the actual &nbsp; on the page and didn't display whitespaces as I would expect.

Comment: It seems the XML is producing as &amp;&nbsp;

Comment: I have used HttpUtility.HtmlDecode to get it working!